# uninitialized constant on nested resource form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models, users, reports, and receipts. Users have many reports, and reports have many receipts.

Now, I have a form set up to create, or edit reports. And I need to nest another form to create and edit receipts. I followed the rails guide (section - building a multi modeled form) and edited my models, and have added the build line into my form view but Im getting that 'uninitialized constant' error.

Here are my models:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
    has_many :receipts

  attr_accessible :cash_advance, :company, :description, :end_date, :mileage, :report_name,
  :start_date, :receipts_attributes

    validates_presence_of :company, :description, :end_date, :report_name#, :start_date
    validates_uniqueness_of :report_name

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :receipts, :allow_destroy => :true,
    :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end

class Receipts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  attr_accessible :account_code, :amount, :company_card, :date, :description, :lobbying_expense, :vendor
end
```

and my form:

```
<%# @report.receipts.build %>
<%= form_for([current_user,@report]) do |f| %>
     ...
    <%= f.fields_for ([@report, @report.receipts.build ]) do |receipt| %>
     ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

my routes (which Im not sure if I should have edited, but I got the same error before I added the receipts resources)

```
resources :users do
    resources :reports do
        resources :receipts
    end
end
```

I didnt edit the reports controller since the rails guide didnt show any mention of it, its its only:

def new
        @report = current_user.reports.new
  end

def edit
        @report = current_user.reports.find(params[:id])
  end

What am I doing wrong?

edit - I changed my form for the receipts so the form_for takes in [@report, @report.receipts.build] but now I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Report::Receipt
```

How do I get this form to work?

Comment: Change `:receipt_attributes` to `:receipts_attributes` in the `attr_accessible` inside `Report` model.

Comment: I think thats only for saving the records, because changing that doesnt prevent the exception error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UGH! I messed up when I generated the model and gave it a plural name instead of a singular name. This guy, right here, is a fool.

Comment: Thats amazing. I was about to post a huge long question, saw your self answered one and was like nahhhh I'm not that dumb. But I am. Go us

Comment: Adding myself to the list of stupid programmers... I am so ashamed.